# How to change sys.argv list elements from strings to ints?

Tags: python

So I tried to convert a list of strings:

```py
['25', '-36', '85', '94', '21', '-68', '-55', '24']
```

into a list of ints like:

```py
[25, -36, 85, 94, 21, -68, -55, 24]
```

So what I did is:

```py
for i in range(len(sys.argv)):
    if isinstance(sys.argv[i], int) == True:
        sys.argv[i] = int(sys.argv[i])
```

But I'm not sure why the items in list are still strings...can someone explain?

Comment: change `isinstance(sys.argv[i], int)` to isinstance(sys.argv[i], str). you want to change it to `int` when it is an instance of `string`

Comment: Since `sys.argv` is always initialized with strings, you don't need that test.

Comment: You're converting elements which are instances of `int` to `int`.

Comment: As @Barmar said, `sys.argv` ***is*** a list of strings, so you don't need to check (besides that, the way you're checking is wrong).

Comment: @martineau As suggested in one of the answers, what I think he's actually trying to check is "if the argv[i] string looks like an int". A common beginner mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Items in `sys.argv` are always string instances when the interpreter loads, so the test `isinstance(sys.argv[i], int)` would always return `False`.

To convert arguments into integers only if they represent integers, you can instead use a `try-except` block around the integer conversion to ignore strings that do not represent integers:

```
for i, s in enumerate(sys.argv):
    try:
        sys.argv[i] = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not running is: it will never get into `if statement`.

`if isinstance(sys.argv[i], int)` will **always** return `False` since your input is a string. And your comparison `isinstance(sys.argv[i], int) == True` will always return `False` either, because you are always comparing `False == True` for any values in your initial string list.

---

The most easy and fast way to make your conversion is using list comprehension:

```
l_str = ['25', '-36', '85', '94', '21', '-68', '-55', '24']

l_int = [int(x) for x in l_str]
```